# Fetching contact is not working in iphone retina 4inch 64bit simulator but works fine in 3.5 inch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am fetching contact first name ,last name ,email id & phone number & loading them in a table view,
every thing is working fine in 3.5inch & 4 inch simulator but when i run the same code on 4inch 64bit simulator it doesnt fetch any contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can act as "separate" phones so be sure that you have added any contact in your iphone retina 64bit aswell